# fancybox/jQuery: Why can't I abort after toclick in a button with some relation with fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

If in the next table I have some rows selected:

```
<table id ="XX">
...
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="1"></td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

I show this dialog:

```
jQuery("#btnActivar").fancybox({
    content: jQuery("#ConfirmacionGuardar").html(),
    modal: false,
    showCloseButton: false,
    onComplete: function () {
       ...
    }
});
```

Always when I click in the button btnActivar open fancybox. I need to abort it when No rows are selected in the same click event of the button

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Impossible to answer your question with more code. How about a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try validating the condition (rows selected?) on `click` before deciding whether firing fancybox or not like :

```
jQuery("#btnActivar").on("click", function () {
    // validate if rows are selected here 
    // returns either true or false, e.g.
    var rows_selected = true;
    // condition true? then fire fancybox programmatically
    if (rows_selected) {
        jQuery.fancybox({
            content: jQuery("#ConfirmacionGuardar").html(),
            modal: false,
            showCloseButton: false,
            onComplete: function () {...
            }
        }); // fancybox
    }; // if
    return false; // otherwise do nothing
}); // on click
```